# UIAnimation not showing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have used this code:

```
[[self.view viewWithTag:100] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.009, 0.009)];
UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
[[self.view viewWithTag:100] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

in `viewWillAppear` of my popup view.
The code works fine on simulator and produces nice effect in which my view appears to grow from center, however on device the animation effect is absent its more like sleep of 0.5 and then all off a sudden view appears.

Since this view is used liberally i don't want to increase duration any help?

Comment: Have you tried to put this code in viewDidApear?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code sample works for me in `viewDidLoad` and  `viewWillAppear`.Increased the time and animation works fine here.
Why use this method?Apple provides a new and better technique with blocks to do the view animations.

Try this

```
[[self.view viewWithTag:100] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.009, 0.009)];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:10.5 animations:^{
        [[self.view viewWithTag:100] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)];
    }];
```